# Jquery: How add new parent to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to add new parent to child. i use this code

```
$("#span").before('<div class="newPaernt">');
```

this add div

```
<div class="newParent"></div><span id="span"></span>
```

not

```
<div class="newParent"><span id="span"></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method is inserting content before an element. For wrapping with an element use [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method.

```
$("#span").wrap('<div class="newPaernt">');
```

```js
$("#span").wrap('<div class="newPaernt">');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span">a</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's wrap method should do the trick:

```js
$('#parent').wrap('<div class="newparent"></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="parent">test your span</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $("<p>Test</p>").insertBefore(".inner");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to do this you can user .wrap function.
http://api.jquery.com/wrap/